# Can you use ProxyPassMatch to change the query string of a URL?

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am not sure if what I'm trying to do is valid, so please bear with me.

I am trying to use the ProxyMassMatch (Apache) Directive through a reverse proxy setup to change URLs which appear on a given page when accessed through my localhost and remove an "sid" parameter. I am aware this particular regex only accounts for when the parameter is not the first cgi arg, but the bigger problem I am having is this doesn't seem to work at all so I'm thinking maybe I do not understand ProxyPassMatch, despite reading the docs multiple times.

To visualize, if this were working, I would be able to mouse-over a url on my "localhost" page and instead of:

```
    http://forums.mysite.com/viewtopic?foo=bar&sid=9746b404cec3e5270f79e6c1de861dae
```

I would see:

```
    http://forums.mysite.com/viewtopic?foo=bar
```

I have successfully removed this cgi arg with mod_rewrite, but because of other mechanisms, I've been asked to do this using ProxyPassMatch so the URLs on the actual page do not display the "sid" parameter. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Here's one of the many variations I've tried in my .conf file.

```
    ProxyPassMatch "(.*forums\.mysite\.com\/viewtopic\.php)(.*[^&]*)(&sid=.*)" "http://localhost/forums.mysite.com/$2"
```